# JSON framework for .NET that can adjust object content at runtime

Tags: c#, json, rest

Right now I am using the JavaScript Serializer to return JSON from a number of REST services as well as having a Dynamic implementation of a "JsonObject" where I can just:

```
dynamic json = new JsonObject();
json.SomeThing = GetSomeThing();
json.AString = "Hello World";
json.Person = new Person{Name="Erik", LastName="Hansen", Age=35};
```

And so on... It handles the conversion at the time where I call "ToString()" and not up front, but that is a minor detail atm. which I'm not sure I have the need for... The JavascriptSerializer comes into the picture on the complex objects filled in the above. (Like Person)

**To Clarify... The above is an implementation that I already have... I Would like to get rid of my own implementation in that regard if I could... Yet be able to keep that "interface"**

What I am looking for is something that might support the above, but it might not need to as I could just keep my current JsonObject, but It would be nice to get rid of obviously...

More importantly, something that supports the scenario described under here...
Taken an example below where we could imagine having a person rest service... Idd like to be able to return partial person objects as shown in the examples below:

```
class Person
{
  string Name;
  string LastName;
  int Age;
  Address Addr;
}

/rest/person/5
Json = { Name: "some name" }

/rest/person/5?Expand=LastName, Age
Json = { Name: "some name", LastName: "Some Last Name", Age: 35 }

/rest/person/5?Expand=Address
Json = { Name: "some name", Address: { ... } }

Nested stuff
/rest/person/5?Expand=Address, Address.Street
Json = { Name: "some name", Address: { Street: "bla" } }
```

Obviously I am not looking for a Framework that goes directly from those "REST" calls into forming the JSON, I just need to be able to control the serialization process enought (in a context) so that I could return persons like above.
Person might not be the root object as well, it could be a list of persons or an object referencing persons...

So Generally on the Client side I would like to be able to same something like:

```
Expand: "Age, LastName"... 
Include: "/rest/address"...
```

The syntax isn't what matters now...

I could keep expanding my own framework for it, but I would rather focus on the actual task and then find a JSON framework that suited my needs... I just either haven't been able to yet, or maybe I just didn't know how to achieve what I needed in that particular framework...

I could properly already do that with the "JavaScript" Serializer and my JsonObject in some manner using Custom type resolvers, but I Would like to search out possibilities that might be easier to use than that...

Also I have noticed that JSON.NET and others perform better than the JavaScript Serializers etc, so why not see if they could support the scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Json.NET has a namespace Newtonsoft.Json.Linq that supports dynamic object generation, and is able to generate from anonymous and complex types

http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/LINQtoJSON.htm

Comment: unfortunetly a simple thing as arrays makes JSON.Net fail, and I would have to explicitly use "JArray" around that... I am considering letting my own JOBject be based on JSON.Net or patch it though.

Comment: Meh... As Json.NET is so wielded into everything today it's become the "right" approach by popularity. although it still seems to lack proper handling of some list cases. - So